# Windows act as title bars on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, compiz

When I enable Compiz (System > Preferences > Appearance > Visual Effects), all the windows start to act funny with the mouse.

Wherever I click on any window with the mouse, it acts as though I was clicking on a titlebar.  I can grab and move the window when I left-click it and when I right-click, the titlebar menu appears.  All this prevents me from touching any object of the window I'm working on.

This happens with minimal, normal or any configuration, and prevents me from using Compiz at all.

BTW, this it a fresh install of 10.04 not an upgrade.  I am re-installing all compiz packages to see if it gets fixed.

I just noticed that the mouses works ok **while I hold down the CTRL button**.

Comment: i'm not sure what effect you're running into, but you might want to install the *compizconfig-settings-manager* package -- CCSM is much more comprehensive than the Appearance > Visual Effects tab.

Comment: It sounds like a setting got inverted (the ctrl modifier part, for example). For example, holding super/winkey and left clicking anywhere in a window allows me to move that window (very useful), but I forget what the default key is for this setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I never found the root cause, so I ended resetting the whole gnome configuration:

```
rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity
```

This wipes the whole desktop configuration.

It's like using a sledgehammer for a small nail, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

run ccsm go to window management -> move window and change "initiate window move" setting to " control button1 "